# Details on why temperature is lower at high altitude

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I have read at so many places that warmer air moves up as hotter substances expands and as it rises it loses its kinetic energy and it gets converted into its potential energy(gravitational+interatomic) And that's what cause decrease in temperature at higher altitude but there is following confusion I have about this:

I want to know it in terms of pressure like is the pressure of the bottom layer of atmosphere increases as its temperature increases because I think that can lead to its flow from higher pressure to lower pressure?but if that happen then as it starts rising there will be a time where pressure drops and become equal to the layers above it so should stop expanding there? So I am confused that is it due to some sort of force(if yes then please explain) or due to random motion of air particles that warmer air expands and moves up?it should be because of some forces pushing it upwards because bulk flow happens due to pressure gradient otherwise it would be diffusion I think pressure should increases because similar think happens in the case hot air ballons moving upwards

2)why the air above this layer comes down as hot air rises? Is this due to diffusion or bulk flow?

If anyone could explain it in terms of forces (Like we do in Newtonian physics) like by making some sort of force diagrams that would be very intuitive and helpful because the main problem is I am unable to form a consistent picture in my mind to understand it.

Comment: I have difficulties to get your question. To 1) hot air expands, meaning less density, so a hot air mass rises until the density equals the density of the surrounding air (like a ballon rises). To 2) could you rephrase or clarify the second question?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/40949/why-less-temperature-at-high-altitude

Comment: 1) the term density u are using I think u are saying it rises because of buoyancy? But if you deeper actually buoyant force is nothing but it arises due to difference in pressure ,so I think u are indirectly saying it rises because it's pressure increases? But then the problem arises as I mentioned above that as it starts rising there will be a time when it's pressure becomes equal to the layers above it then it should stop rising but that doesn't happen? So is it just pure diffusion and nothing else?

Comment: And in my 2nd question I want to know as the lower layer rises why the upper layers comes down? Is it just the gravity? And in the hot air ballon case the hot air pressure applied on the ballon should be very high for sure otherwise it can't lift the weight it carries

Comment: " _that as it starts rising there will be a time when it's pressure becomes equal to the layers above it then it should stop rising but that doesn't happen?_ " Why do you think that does not happen ? Do you think it just keeps on rising for ever and ever without ever stopping ?

Comment: No,I think you are not getting what I am saying please read this question then u will get it please read the edited part that is must https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/660007/why-should-layers-of-air-rise-up-and-the-layer-above-it-takes-it-place/660018?noredirect=1#comment1480350_660018